# Regular expressions and equivalence classes

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I need a little help regarding this problem:
Let L = {w ∈ {0, 1} ∗ : w has an even number of 0s and the last character of w is a 1}. Give the equivalence classes of the relation ≡L using regular expressions.

What does it mean with equivalence classes?
Is it right that i have found a regular expression for it:
1*(1*01*0)1 --(i think this a right regular expression)

Comment: An equivalence class w.r.t. an equivalence relation $\equiv$  is a maximal (w.r.t. set inclusion) subset $C$ of $L$ such that $x,y \in C$ if and only if $x \equiv y$. We cannot possibly know what the equivalence classes w.r.t. $\equiv_L$ are unless you define $\equiv_L$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you help me with an example for this problem so i can continue in my own : Let L = {w ∈ {0, 1} ∗ : w has an even number of 0s and the last character of w is a 1}. Give the equivalence classes of the relation ≡L using regular expressions.

Comment: How is $\equiv_L$ defined?

Comment: that is all the info i have .I think =L has to be found from the given exercise or am i wrong?

Comment: From what I understand you are supposed to know what $\equiv_L$ means already. The equivalence relation $\equiv_L$ partitions $L$ (or perhaps $\Sigma^*$?) into a collection (called quotient set) of equivalence classes.  The exercise is asking you to describe these equivalence classes by providing a regular expression for each class. We cannot possibly know what these classes are unless we know what $\equiv_L$ is.

Comment: Ok,thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess and assume that $\equiv_L$ is defined as the set of all pairs $(x,y) \in \Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*$ such that either (i) $x \in L$ and $y \in L$, or (ii) $x \not\in L$ and $y \not\in L$.

In this case $\Sigma^* / \equiv_L$ contains two equivalence classes, namely $L$ itself and its complement $\Sigma^* \setminus L$.

A regular expression for $L$ is $1^*(01^*01^*)^*1$. Essentially we make sure that $0$s always come in pairs and that the last character is a $1$.

A regular expression for $\Sigma^* \setminus L$ is $\varepsilon \mid (0\mid1)^*0 \mid 1^*(01^*01^*)^*01^*$.
The first part of the regular expression (i.e., $\varepsilon$) matches the empty word. The second part (i.e., $(0\mid1)^*0$) matches all words that end with $0$, and the third part (i.e., $1^*(01^*01^*)^*01^*$) matches all words with an odd number of $0$s.

---

As Nir Shahar points out, another definition of $\equiv_L$ could be $x \equiv_L y$ if and only if $\not\exists z \in \mathbb \Sigma^*$ such that either (i) $xz \in L$  and $yz \not\in L$ or (ii) $xz \not\in L$  and $yz \in L$. This is the definition used in the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), and word $z$ satisfying either (i) or (ii) is called a distinguishing extension for $x$ and $y$.

In this case $\Sigma^* / \equiv_L$ contains the following classes:

- $C_1$: The set of all words that have an even number of $0$s and end with $1$, i.e., $L$ itself. A regular expression for $C_1$ is given above.
- $C_2$: The set of all words that have an odd number of $0$s. A regular expression for $C_2$ is given above.
- $C_3$: The set of all words that have an even number of $0$s but do not end with $1$. A regular expression for $C_3$ is $(1^* 0 1^* 0)^*$.

It is easy to see that $C_1, C_2, C_3$ partition $\Sigma^*$. We just need to show that (A) any two words in $x,y \in C_i$ satisfy $x \equiv_L y$, and (B) for $i \neq j$ there are two words $x \in C_i$, $y \in C_j$ that do not satisfy $x \equiv_L y$.

**Regarding (A):**
If $z$ were a distinguishing extensions for either two words in $x,y \in C_1$ or two words $x,y \in C_3$, then since at least one of $xz$ and $xz$ must belong to $L$ and we must have $z \neq \varepsilon$, $z$ must end with $1$ and must contain an even number of zeroes. However, any such $z$ is such that both $xz \in L$ and $xz \in L$.

If $z$ were a distinguishing extensions for two words in $x,y, \in C_2$, then since at least one of $xz$ and $xz$ must belong to $L$, $z$ must end with $1$ and must contain an odd number of zeroes. However, any such $z$ is such that both $xz \in L$ and $xz \in L$.

**Regarding (B):** $\varepsilon$ is a distinguishing extension for $1 \in C_1$ and $0 \in C_2$. $1$ is a distinguishing extension for $0 \in C_2$ and $\varepsilon \in C_3$. Finally, $\varepsilon$ is a distinguishing extension for $1 \in C_1$ and $\varepsilon \in C_3$.

Comment: My first guess to $\equiv_L$ would actually be something different: $x,y\in \Sigma^*$, and $x\equiv_L y\iff$ there is no distinguishing extension of $x$ and $y$ (that is, the equivalence relation is the Nerode relation over $L$)

Comment: @nirshahar. Good point. I expanded my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Also, it might be easier to understand if you would write $\forall z, xz\in L\iff yz\in L$ instead of $\not \exists z \dots$. But on the other hand, this definition does not easily define what a "distinguishing extension" is.